# How to request HealthKit permissions for HKWorkout type?

Tags: ios, healthkit

I am working with `HKWorkout` for the same time, and I'm not clearly seeing how these types work. I am used to `HKQuantityType` but this is not a direct translation. In particular, how can I request permission to read certain types in the HKStore? In particular I am trying to request permission for `HKWorkoutActivityTypeEquestrianSports` but I am not managing to produce the correct type of object.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply request authorization to read/write samples of the `HKWorkout` sample type. There are not fine-grained authorization controls for each individual activity type, such as `HKWorkoutActivityTypeEquestrianSports`, in HealthKit.